# O: Android XmlPullParser cannot process xml-FIle (finds only STARTDOCUMENT)

Tags: java, android, xmlpullparser

in an android app, i got the following xml resulting from xmlSerializer:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><Network><Cubes><Cube CubeName="null" CubeRF="0cd86d" CubeSN="EQ0837268" /></Cubes><Raeume><Raum RaumName="Wohnzimmer" RaumID="1" RaumRF="b715a" /><Raum RaumName="Schlafzimmer" RaumID="2" RaumRF="b7a40" /><Raum RaumName="Bￃﾼro" RaumID="3" RaumRF="b7128" /><Raum RaumName="Badezimmer" RaumID="4" RaumRF="b6e0b" /><Raum RaumName="Gￃﾤstezimmer" RaumID="5" RaumRF="b602f" /></Raeume><Devices><Thermostat DevName="Schlafen" DevRF="b7a40" DevType="1" DevSer="KEQ0446747" DevRaumID="2" /><Thermostat DevName="Bￃﾼro" DevRF="b7128" DevType="1" DevSer="KEQ0449549" DevRaumID="3" /><Thermostat DevName="Bad" DevRF="b6e0b" DevType="1" DevSer="KEQ0446180" DevRaumID="4" /><Thermostat DevName="Wohnzimmer" DevRF="b715a" DevType="1" DevSer="KEQ0449570" DevRaumID="1" /><Thermostat DevName="Gￃﾤstezimmer" DevRF="b602f" DevType="1" DevSer="KEQ0450567" DevRaumID="5" /></Devices></Network>
```

(not edited afterwards)
But when i want to process this with the XmlPullParser, the eventType always remains 0 - looks for me that the XmlPullParser doesn't recognize any other tag.

The code i use for processing (as i'm german, i use german function names):

```
public void ladeXmlDatenInCubeNetz(String xmlDatenDateiName) {
        String xmlDatenString = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream xmlDateiInput =  new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/ccdat.xml"));
            InputStreamReader xmlInputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(xmlDateiInput);
            char[] EingabePuffer = new char[xmlDateiInput.available()];
            xmlInputStreamReader.read(EingabePuffer);
            xmlDatenString = new String(EingabePuffer);
            XmlPullParserFactory factory =   XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(xmlDatenString));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

        cDevice4 cd = new cDevice4();
        CubeNetz.clear();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {     
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("Cube")) {
                            cd.setDeviceTypeSelector(0);    
                            cd.setCubeCubeName(xpp.getAttributeValue("", "CubeName"));
                            cd.setCubeCubeRFAddress(xpp.getAttributeValue("", "CubeRF"));
cd.setCubeCubeSerialNumber(xpp.getAttributeValue("", "CubeSN"));
                            CubeNetz.add(cd);
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equals("Raum")) {
                            cd.setDeviceTypeSelector(1);
                            cd.setRaumName(xpp.getAttributeValue("", "RaumName"));
                            String rid = xpp.getAttributeValue("", "RaumID");
                            cd.setRaumID(Byte.valueOf(rid));
                            String aktRaumRF = xpp.getAttributeValue("", "RaumRF");
                            CubeNetz.add(cd);
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equals("Thermostat")) {
                            cd.setDeviceTypeSelector(2);
                            cd.setDeviceName(xpp.getAttributeValue("", "DevName"));
                            cd.setDeviceRFAddress(xpp.getAttributeValue("", "DevRF"));
                            cd.setDeviceSeriennummer(xpp.getAttributeValue("", "DevSer"));
                            cd.setDeviceRoomID(Integer.valueOf(xpp.getAttributeValue("", "DevRaumID")));
                            CubeNetz.add(cd);
                        }
                    }
                }
                try {
                    xpp.next();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }

        xmlInputStreamReader.close();
        xmlDateiInput.close();

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The class cDevice4 contains the implementation for accessing an ELV MaxCube-System (Heating control).

I checked the Xml-File with some online-validators and it seems to be correct.
So where do i have to change my code that i can process this file?
Thanks in advance
GU_Meyer

Comment: user java-json.jar to convert xml into json

Comment: Do i understand that such as that it would be easier to use json?
But it must be possible to read an xml-file with the xmlPullparser, even if the file is generated by the xmlSerializer (Both are specified for Android).

Comment: Solved! Changing the code to the following reads the file correctly:

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Changing the code to the following (extracted only the relevant code) reads the file correctly:

```
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG :
                        if (xpp.getName().equals("Cube")) {
// (Rest of code for here)
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equals("Raum")) {
// (Rest of code for here)                          
                        } else if (xpp.getName().equals("Thermostat")) {
// (Rest of code for here)
                        }
                        break;
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
```

So, the replacement of the if...then {} by a switch...case  solved it.
Thanks to all thinking about my problem.